# Running Nodejs application on VPS OVH

Tags: node.js, port, vps

I just rent a VPS at OVH and i'm trying to run a Nodejs application on port 1337.
The application runs correctly, when I try :

```
curl 0.0.0.0:1337
```

It gives me the code of the page (works with `127.0.0.1` too)

But when I try to connect to `176.31.184.111:1337`, it doesn't work.

```
#root: iptables -L -v -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 8645 packets, 592K bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source           destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source           destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7556 packets, 729K bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source           destination
```

Comment: can we see the code? i suspect you're only listening locally (127.0.0.1) instead of on all devices (0.0.0.0).

Comment: Hi, my app is on: https://github.com/LaPatatePourrie/nodejs.

Comment: can you paste the code into the post